# 1D Wave equations other than sinusoidal waves which can be graphed on Desmos Graph

Tags: waves, computational-physics, software

I want to see waves equation other than the usual sine waves (or damped sine wave).
Im especially interested in graphing them on Desmos.

I have searched but everywhere either $sin(kx-wt)$ is shown or 2D/3D wave equations are given.

It will really great if someone could mention a few wave equations that are solutions of the general differential wave equation.

Comment: Every function of the form $f(kx-wt)+g(kx+wt)$ solves the wave equation, so you have the choice.

Comment: log and tan of (kx-wt) dont seem to give any 'waves'(Do they?). Can you please give me some function I can copy paste on desmos?

Comment: How do you define 'wave', then?

Comment: @RohitShekhawat Still, it is any function you like. You could plot a sawtooth or square wave as they are one of the simplest waves after the sine wave. A sawtooth is just arcsin(sin(x)). A gaussian is also nice exp(-x^2)

Comment: ... or $\sec\left(A \sin\left(x\right)\right)$, for the fun-looking chart give a shot for $A\sin\left(B\tan\left(x\right)\right)$, experiment.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Wow, e^(-x^2) is AMAZING! I always thought of it as a randomly created function, never thought of it as a wave pulse(never visualised it).